# Phonegap android add windowSoftInputMode using config.xml

Tags: android, cordova, android-manifest

I am creating a `phonegap` application and for android build I want to set the `windowSoftInputMode` property of Andriod manifest file  using `config.xml`.

Is there any way to do it using config.xml or command line.Kindly suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

Add following preference in your `config.xml` file :

```
<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="stateVisible|adjustResize" />
```

Also you have to disable the full-screen preference :

```
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="false" />
```

Check more :

- [Android+PhoneGap: android:windowSoftInputMode doesn't seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989890/androidphonegap-androidwindowsoftinputmode-doesnt-seem-to-work)
- [Cordova Bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/i#browse/CB-4404)